# Redirect Links 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have question about 301 Redirect please:

example:

http://stackapp.com/post/35642

to:

**http://google.com/posts/index.php?q=http://stackapp.com/post/35642**

Note: I want to redirect all posts.(Not just the ID = 35642 post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 (post/.*) http://google.com/posts/index.php?q=http://stackapp.com/$1
```